# Java calculating area/circumference of a circle using double and int w/ return

Tags: java, methods, calculation, pi

I'm a very beginner in programming Java and I need to solve this task. I've got a preset and need to implement a method. The method needs to contain the contant PI.
My task is "The radius is set via the parameter list either in mm (double)
or passed in px(int). The calculated value is returned in the same unit of measurement via the return interface
returned (with return). If the radius is < 0, the calculation of the perimeter and area is 0"

```
public class Methods {

     public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

     static double calCircumference(double radius) {
     return 2 * PI * radius;
}

     static double calArea(double radius) {
     return PI * radius * radius;
}

     static int calCircumference(int radius) {
     return 2 * PI * radius;
}

     static int calArea(int radius) {
     return PI * radius * radius;
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        { // Test Calculate Circle double
            double radius = 5.00;
            System.out.printf("Radius =  %10.2f mm.\n", radius);
            System.out.printf("Circumference =  %10.2f mm.\n", calCircumference(radius));
            System.out.printf("Area = %10.2f mm.^2\n", calArea(radius));
            radius = -5.00;
            System.out.printf("Radius =  %10.2f mm.\n", radius);
            System.out.printf("Circumference =  %10.2f mm.\n", calCircumference(radius));
            System.out.printf("Area = %10.2f mm.^2\n", calArea(radius));
        }
        { // Test Calculate Circle int
            int radius = 5;
            System.out.printf("Radius =  %10d px.\n", radius);
            System.out.printf("Circumference =  %10d px.\n", calCircumference(radius));
            System.out.printf("Area = %10d px.^2\n", calArea(radius));
            radius = -5;

                    System.out.printf("Radius =  %10d px.\n", radius);
            System.out.printf("Circumference =  %10d px.\n", calCircumference(radius));
            System.out.printf("Area = %10d px.^2\n", calArea(radius));
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
Radius =        5,00 mm.
Circumference =       31,42 mm.
Area =      78,54 mm.^2
Radius =       -5,00 mm.
Circumference =      -31,42 mm.
Area =      78,54 mm.^2
Radius =           5 px.
Circumference =  Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4442)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2963)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2918)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2689)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1209)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1105)
    at Methoden.main(Methoden.java:40)
```

Comment: The format specifier for floating point numbers (`float` and `double`) is `%f`, not `%d`.

Comment: Cast to **int**: `int calCircumference(int radius) { return (int) (2 * PI * radius); }` and `int calArea(int radius) { return (int) (PI * radius * radius); }`.

Comment: You can also use `Math.PI` as the value.  Check out the [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) class for more useful methods and constants.

Comment: for your `int calCircumference(int radius)` and `int calArea (int radius)`, you should consider if you just want to get the whole number portion of the floating number result. or do you want to round up/down the number. e.g., if the calculated value is 5.678. doing type casting like what @DevilsHnd suggested will result in an integer of 5. you can also use `.intValue()` function which can give you the same outcome. But if you are expecting 5.678 to round to 6 instead of 5, you should use Math.round() in combination with type casting. like this `return (int) Math.round(2 * PI * radius);`